# Log4Net MVC3 configuration - no records created

Tags: .net, log4net

I'm trying to get the hello-world log4net sample going from an empty MVC3 project without much luck so far ,

in my Views\web.config

```
<log4net>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=dbname;user id=user;password=pw" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
```

in global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
        log.Info("stuff");
        log.Info("stuff");

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Create script for DB

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Thread] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Level] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Logger] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Message] [varchar](4000) NOT NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Can anyone spot what might be missing here?

Thanks

more info: log4net 1.2.11.0, and write to log file works fine so this seems to be db related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have exception column in your create statement